# How can I add an index to a SQL Server CE table created programmatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, windows-ce, ddl

I'm using code like this to create SQL Server CE tables:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, Description nvarchar(255), DeptDotSubdept float, UnitCost float, UnitList float, UPCCode nvarchar(50), UPCPackSize smallint, CRVId int);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I need to add an index, too. Do I do it like so:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, Description nvarchar(255), DeptDotSubdept float, UnitCost float, UnitList float, UPCCode nvarchar(50), UPCPackSize smallint, CRVId int);
CREATE INDEX idxUnitCost ON InventoryItems (UnitCost) ASC";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

...(where the command text contains two semi-colon delimited DDL statements) or like so:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, Description nvarchar(255), DeptDotSubdept float, UnitCost float, UnitList float, UPCCode nvarchar(50), UPCPackSize smallint, CRVId int);"
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX idxUnitCost ON InventoryItems (UnitCost) ASC";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

...(command, execute, command, execute) or some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two separate commands.  SQL Compact won't allow you to do multiple commands at a time.